# Distorted images in Qlabel

Tags: python, image, pyqt4, qlabel

I'm using Qlabel(PyQt4) to display images in my application. The image looks distorted when application renders it for the first time. But second time onwards (After closing the window and reopening it) the image is displayed without distortion. How to avoid the distortion in the image when it is displayed for the first time?

Image with distortion
[image]

Image without distortion
[image]

Code Snippet:

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(image))
scaledPixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.wCam0.ui.lblImage.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
self.wCam0.ui.lblImage.setPixmap(scaledPixmap)
```

In the above snippet, self.wCam0.ui.lblImage is the Qlabel object and image is the location/path of the image that needs to be displayed.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I tried removing FastTransformation but still, the image looks distorted for the first time

Comment: what is the size and weight of the image? Have you tried with other images of different sizes, weights
 and qualities?

Comment: @SanketDeshmukh. The image is distorted because you chose to distort it. That's what can happen when you resize an image whilst igoring the aspect ratio.